# How to find combined SSE?

Tags: regression, self-study, sampling, standard-error

[image]For example, if we know that for a sample includes 107 income households, the SSE is 10.8. And for another sample including 98 income households, the SSE is 9.2. How to find the combined SSE for the all 225 samples?

Comment: From the sample sizes, $R^2$, and $s_U^2$, you should be able to find the variance of the monthly expenditures.  From the additional information in (b) you should now be able to carry out an analysis of variance for the INCOME variable.

Comment: I am confused.. Why are you all talking about variance? Isn't F test only about SSR and n and k?

Comment: An $F$ test, by definition, compares variances.  The variances to compare must somehow reflect the difference in mean monthly expenditures between the low and high groups.  That can be revealed by comparing the residual variances to the total variance.  (That's why this is called "Analysis of Variance.")  One way or another, however you express it algebraically, your test *must* come down to such a comparison.  I believe that the point of this series of questions may be to help you appreciate that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the Chow statistic:

$$
F=\frac{SSR_p-(SSR_1+SSR_2)}{SSR_1+SSR_2} \cdot \frac{n-2(k+1)}{k+1}
$$
Where SSR is the sum of squared residuals (or errors if you prefer). K is the number of explanatory variables, n is the total sample. The subscript p refers to the model where you pool all observations, while 1 and 2 refer to the groups number.

The trick about this question is to realize that you can work out $SSR_p$ from variance estimate in (a). Since the variance follows from:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{u}_i^2 / (n-k-1) = s^2_u
$$
Where n and k has the same definition as above, and the sum of squared residuals are given by $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{u}_i^2$.

The Chow test directly compares if there is difference in all the estimated parameters between the groups, which is what the question in (b) asked you verify.

Comment: But all we know is SSE, and what is SRR?

Comment: SSE = sum of squared errors = SSR = sum of squared residuals. They are the same thing

Comment: They are not? SST= SSR+ SSE. That's what I learnt.

Comment: And what is $SSR_p$ in your answer?

Comment: See the update...

Comment: So $SSR_p$ is the sum of all of the estimated error listed in the pic? And $SSR_1+SSR_2=10.8+9.2=20$?

Comment: Then F is just equal to 0?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me...

Comment: Whoops sorry, $SSR_p$ should be worked out from the model in (a). Please ignore my comments above, you easily do this since you know the variance of the residuals. Will update the answer later to reflect what is right

Comment: Thank you very much.. but I still don't know how to approach it.

Comment: How to work out $SSR_p$ knowing the variance?

Comment: Did you see the update?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a meaningful practice to calculate a combined SSE in my view- What are you trying to get out of that? You need to combine both sample first and fit one linear regression to the whole data space and then calculate the overall SSE, which accounts for the total error of your regression line to the fitted data.

Comment: Because I need to know the SSE to apply F test. And I was given the data above..

Comment: I've inserted the pic to the original question. Part b, that's the only way I can think of for solving part b.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the F-test is used to test whether the ratio of two SSE measures is equal to 1, in other words, whether the two SSE measures are equal:

$F_{(n_1-1, n_2-1)} = \frac{MSE_1}{MSE_2}$

Where $F$ is from the $F$-distribution with $n_1-1$ and $n_2-1$ degrees of freedom.

However, I don't think it is meaningful to compare $SSE_{low}$ and $SSE_{high}$ in such a way, because there would be little to learn from it and it doesn't answer the question. Usually in ANOVAs the $SSE_{variable}$ is compared to the $RSS$ (Residual Sum of Squares), but it is not immediately obvious where to find those in this problem.

Comment: The $R^2$ is given, and from that, we can learn the ratio of SST and SSR, but that's it.. I still don't know how to solve it and how to connect what I've known to SSE.

Comment: The given $R^2$ is from the regression model, but in question b they turn it into an ancova by discretizing the income variable. I am not sure whether you can still use the $R^2$ in that case.

Comment: So do you have any idea how to solve part b?

Comment: I am still stuck and lost...